# How to get following and followers of google plus user using Google People AP ?

Tags: google-people-api

I followed the following tutorial http://blog.grafixartist.com/people-api-android-tutorial-1/. I am not getting any followers or following Google plus friends in the response of Google People API. It only gives contacts information.

Answer (score 0):

It isn't possible to get followers or followed people from the Google People API.